# SQL Join Two Tables on Column

Tags: sql, database

There are two tables Department and Employee
Department:

```
DID DName           PhoneExt 
ADM Administration  100 
CLT Client Services 101 
DAT Data Conversion 102 

EMPLOYEE
EID EName Salary   MID   DID 
e001 Martin 57000        CLT 
e002 West 39000   e001   CLT 
e003 Wilson 64000        DAT 
e004 Patel 48000  e003   DAT 
e005 Rae 42000    e001   CLT 
e006 Jones 36000  e003   DAT 
e007 Dunn 52000   e003   PRG
```

How can I list the names and ids of those employees whose manager is from the Client 
Services department?

Comment: client services has a DID on CLT.  Select * from employee where DID = 'CLT' will work.  If you want to do it by the full DName, then you need an inner join.  Very basic SQL, give it a try first, if you are still having issues, post your attempt up and we'll be happy to help

Comment: Explain the question more detail. How should be your output look like.

Comment: Overflowers always like it when you use good grammar and format your data in an easy-to-read way! :)

Answer (score 2):

List the names and ids:

```
SELECT EName, EID
```

of those employees:

```
FROM EMPLOYEE
```

whose manager is from:

```
WHERE MID IN
```

the Client Services department:

```
(SELECT EID FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE DID = 'CLT')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e1.* FROM employee e1 WHERE e1.MID IN 
  (SELECT e2.EID FROM employee e2 WHERE e2.DID = 'CLT')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT EID, EName FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE MID IN (SELECT EID FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE DID = 'CLT')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a subquery is fine (as suggested by Dour, Mohamed, Rafa, ...), however, you can do this more efficiently (without a subquery) by self-joining the employee table:

```
SELECT
   emp.Ename,
   emp.EID
FROM
   EMPLOYEE emp

   INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE mngr
   ON emp.MID = mngr.EID
WHERE
   mngr.DID = 'CLT'
```

Note -- you don't actually need to use the department table at all...